# Petapoco execute stored procedure without waiting

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, petapoco

I'm using PetaPoco on a C# WepApi and I have to execute a Stored Procedure that deletes rows on many tables. The number of rows to delete it's variable (can be a few or too many) so, sometimes, PetaPoco throws an Exception of timeout. Is it possible, with PetaPoco, to "call" the stored procedure and close the connection before the procedure is done. The Stored Procedure doesn't return any value and the WebApi doesn't need to know when it's over...

Comment: you can't close the ADO.NET connection - that will terminate things, and either leave things incomplete, or force a rollback (depending on transactions). Async might be an option. Otherwise, ExecuteReader (on ADO.NET) offers a "close the connection when you're done" option via `CommandBehavior`

Comment: This is the real answer I was looking. Can or cannot be done. thanks

Answer (score 6):

What you need it's to fire a background task and return from the WebApi request. [The are several options to run a background task](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) and don't forget to change the request timeout using :

```
HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 50 * 60; // 50 minutes
```

and the PetaPoco command timeout using:

```
var db = new Database(connectionStringName);
db.OneTimeCommandTimeout = 50 * 60; // 50 minutes
db.Execute( ... );
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the OneTimeCommandTimeout because I can't predict the time that will take to execute the Stored Procedure but it looks like I have no other option

Comment: In ADO you can set up the CommandTimeout to zero to get infinite, but PetaPoco only sets the option if it's greater than zero. If you can change the source code, maybe that's the solution